# Rails asset css.erb is not loading

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, markdown, redcarpet, rouge

I'm configuring Markdown in Rails 4 with Redcarpet and Rouge. And I'm following [this simple post](http://www.brettdemetris.com/posts/4)

Everything is working fine (both in development and production) except that my file `assets/stylesheets/rouge.css.erb` seems not to be loading. And it looks like this now:

```
<%= Rouge::Themes::Github.render(:scope => '.highlight') %>

.highlight {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 25em;
}

.highlight .err {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Because whatever I put in it there would be no difference in the output, which looks the same, like this

[image]

And I guess syntax highlighting is not present for the same reason. And it doesn't work in both development and production.
So what could be my mistake?

I'm a complete newbie to it and I may have missed something important. So tell me if you want me to provide any other info on this matter.

UPDATE 1

For those who sees a mistake in my using `.css.erb` and going to downvote me, see 2.3.1 in [the rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) first

Comment: Are you sure its `rouge.css.erb` not `rouge.css.scss`?

Comment: File extension should `css.scss` or just `.css` not `css.erb`.

Comment: guys, see 2.3.1 [in rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets)

Comment: @borderline i believe thats not true, see my previous answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. I've found the answer myself. A couple of days ago I was searching for a solution for a problem of my production server being slow. And I found (here) a suggestion to set these two lines in `development.rb` to `false`

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.assets.debug = false
```

and it turned out that the second line caused my problem. I returned it back to `true` and everything works. But i don't understand why it didn't affect bootstrap styles

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

it was missing

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```